# Write batch file to read a number from a text file and execute the command with that number

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file and a .bat file. Int the text file I have a list of workstation numbers like:

```
CG002681
CG002526
CG002527
CG002528
CG002529
CG002530
....
```

so I need to read this text file and i need to excute the command as shown below.

```
copy "\\cg002009\c$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\abc\LM\I4S.INI" c:\asd\mul.txt 
echo cg002009 >> c:\asd\Shashi.txt
type c:\asd\mul.txt >> c:\asd\345.txt \l
```

I need execute this command for each workstation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`for`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) command:

```
for /F %F in (test.txt) do echo %F
```

will print each line in file test.txt to the console.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for /F %%F in (test.txt) do echo %%F`

Comment: @JeffCaron: Yes, within a batch file you need to double the percentage sign.

Answer (score 1):

`for /F "delims= " %%i in (workstation.txt) do call handle.bat %%i`

in handle.bat first param (%1) will be name of workstation there you can do all work (copy, echo and so on)